# rest android to gae datastore objectify

Tags: android, google-app-engine, rest, datastore, objectify

i'm new to android using the rest framework and is connecting to GAE server. Store the data from android to GAE using datastore objectify
can anyone help me solve this errors?

```
11-29 14:23:13.421: I/ApplicationPackageManager(13615): cscCountry is not German : XTC
11-29 14:23:23.609: I/ApplicationPackageManager(13615): cscCountry is not German : XTC
11-29 14:23:27.273: D/dalvikvm(13615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 220K, 48% free 2987K/5639K, external 508K/517K, paused 4ms+4ms
11-29 14:23:38.609: D/dalvikvm(13615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 316K, 47% free 3176K/5895K, external 508K/517K, paused 3ms+5ms
11-29 14:23:38.773: D/dalvikvm(13615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 227K, 45% free 3408K/6087K, external 508K/517K, paused 3ms+3ms
11-29 14:23:38.968: D/dalvikvm(13615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 261K, 42% free 3698K/6343K, external 508K/517K, paused 3ms+8ms
11-29 14:23:39.187: D/dalvikvm(13615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 265K, 41% free 3950K/6599K, external 508K/517K, paused 4ms+5ms
11-29 14:23:39.203: I/org.restlet(13615): Starting the default HTTP client
11-29 14:23:50.695: I/global(13615): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 628ms.
11-29 14:23:50.703: I/PortalUserController(13615): Creation failed !
11-29 14:23:50.703: I/(13615): Method Not Allowed
11-29 14:23:50.703: I/System.out(13615): Method Not Allowed
```

//here is the whole class

public class PortalUserController {

```
 public final ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(
         ServerConfiguration.gae_path + "/rest/user");

         public PortalUserController() {
             ServerConfiguration.getInstance();
         }

         public void create(PortalUser user) throws Exception {
         final PortalUserControllerInterface uci = cr.wrap(PortalUserControllerInterface.class);

         try {
         uci.create(user);

         Log.i("PoralUserController", "Creation success !");
         } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.i("PortalUserController", "Creation failed !");
         Log.i("", e.getMessage());
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         throw e;
         }
         }

         public List<PortalUser>getAllUsers() {
         final PortalUserControllerInterface uci = cr
         .wrap(PortalUserControllerInterface.class);
         DataContainer content = uci.getAllUsers();
         return content.getUser_list();
         }
```

}

thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Method Not Allowed"
```

You are using the wrong method, that is : you might be sending GET where the server only accepts POST on given URL;